# Excel VBA: How to push data to an exclusive range on another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I use the sub below as part of another sub which error checks and saves a grade sheet.  There will be at least 39 grade sheets generated throughout the course this is built for.  Each event may be accomplished more than once - a weather cancel, or student failed.

The FindEmptyInsertData sub takes the three most important data from a grade sheet (Date, Grade, Status) and adds them to a sheet named Index.  Index then keeps a running tally on the events accomplished...based solely on the output of the 'Error Check and Save' macro.

My question is more of a logic question, rather than for specific code (although it'll help).  FindEmptyInsertData works wonderfully.  However, the data gets pushed and added to Index however many times the user clicks the 'Error Check and Save' Form Control button.  I would like it to only get pushed once per grade sheet...the problem/challenge is that a user might need to go back and change the grade sheet (wrong date, different status...etc).

Index looks like this:

```
    Event   ABC-1   ABC-2   DEF-1   DEF-2
    Date    dd-mmm  dd-mmm  dd-mmm  dd-mmm
    Grade     1        2      2       3
    Status    WX      EFF    EFF     EFF
            ----    ----    ----    ----
    Date    dd-mmm
    Grade     3
    Status   EFF
```

I'm thinking that my solution will lie in the fact that only one event will ever be attempted/accomplished per day.  Therefore...if date of gradesheet matches the date in index, then don't push the data again...except if the grade or status changes.  Ugh, my brain hurts!

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub FindEmptyInsertData()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim gsDate As Date
Dim gsWorking As String
Dim gsMsnNum As String
Dim colNum As Integer

gsWorking = ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.Name
gsDate = ActiveSheet.Range("S3")
gsGrade = ActiveSheet.Range("D40")
gsStatus = ActiveSheet.Range("O7")
gsMsnNum = ActiveSheet.Range("D3")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    'Opens up the INDEX (Sheet4) and finds the first empty cell
        Sheet4.Activate
        Sheet4.Unprotect

    'Finds the sortie name column in INDEX
        For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Rows(5).Cells
        If Cell = gsMsnNum Then Cell.Select: Exit For
        Next Cell

    'Takes the active column number and assigns it to the variable
        colNum = ActiveCell.Column

    'Finds the first open cell in that column
        For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum).Cells
        If Len(Cell) = 0 Then Cell.Select: Exit For
        Next Cell

    ActiveCell.Value = gsDate 'Prints the Date from the GS into the first empty cell
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm"

        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Moves One Cell Down

    ActiveCell.Value = gsGrade 'Prints the Grade from the GS

        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Moves One Cell Down

    ActiveCell.Value = gsStatus 'Prints the Status from the GS
    ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium 'Adds a bottom border

    'Protects the Index Page
    Sheet4.Protect



    'Returns to the Previously open GS
    Worksheets(gsWorking).Activate


End Sub
```

Comment: I admire the way you laid out your question, and the effort to prove that you have spent hours thinking about it. However, it is still difficult for me to understand what it is you are trying to achieve. One way to do that is to use a simple flow chart to explain in an abstract view what your code is doing, before going to details.

Comment: After extracting a value, format the source cell in some way that you can recognize if the code is run again, and if detected then don't perform the copy. Or place a "Copied" flag in a cell on the source sheet.

Comment: @Ahmad Thank you very much.  I posted my solution below, and guess how I came up with the answer?  I grabbed a dry-erase marker and drew out what I needed the code to do.  I'm quickly figuring out that time spent with "pencil and paper" is immensely more productive than hacking at code that I'm just learning.

Comment: @TimWilliams - I did not know that cells could be flagged that way!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your Index and other code involved, this is the best recommendation I could make.

Conceptually, as far as simple database design goes, you might benefit from adding a 5th row for Event Sequence.
Add an integer variable to your code that looks for the sequence and when assigning data for an event. Increment it by 1 when adding event data to the index. If you hate the idea of consuming an entire row you can also tell your code to hide the row.

This way you can have as many entries containing same or different data as necessary. You can choose to accept the "Event" and highest number for "Sequence" as the final submitted grade by default.

```
Event   ABC-1   ABC-2   DEF-1   DEF-2
-------------------------------------
Seq       1        1      1       1    ' <--- Pull data by Event Name & Sequence
Date    dd-mmm  dd-mmm  dd-mmm  dd-mmm
Grade     1        2      2       3
Status    WX      EFF    EFF     EFF
         ----    ----    ----    ----
Seq       2                            ' <--- Pull data by Event Name & Sequence
Date    dd-mmm
Grade     3
Status   EFF
```

---

Additionally, you could add another row to the Index that would contain data for which event is the active one that you have pushed to the grade sheet.

```
Event   ABC-1   ABC-2   DEF-1   DEF-2
-------------------------------------
Seq       1        1      1       1   ' <--- Pull data by Event Name & Sequence
Date    dd-mmm  dd-mmm  dd-mmm  dd-mmm
Grade     1        2      2       3
Status    WX      EFF    EFF     EFF
Active    0        1      1       1
         ----    ----    ----    ----
Seq       2                            ' <--- Pull data by Event Name & Sequence
Date    dd-mmm
Grade     3
Status   EFF
Active    1
```

Comment: Thank you!  Although I did think of a similar solution as you did, I got the "date" way to work...although yours if definitely a more fool-proof solution.  If I have issues, this is the way I'll go.  Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your answer!  I had the same kind of idea as you as I went to bed last night thinking about how to solve this...to give each event a unique identifier that gets pulled along with the other data.  I knew this was going to be more of a logic type answer, with multiple ways to solve (like anything in life, eh?).

BUT...what I ended up going with (for now at least), was sticking with using the Date tied to the Event Name as the 'unique' qualifiers.  I realize that there are some gaps in this logic (what if the date gets changed after the data push?) that your solution will solve.  But, the date is auto generated with the Grade Sheet, so I'm hoping the occurrence will be virtually non-existent.

For anyone else out there reading my first(!) post here, here's my solution:

```
'Finds the Event name column in INDEX
        For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Rows(5).Cells
        If Cell = gsMsnNum Then Cell.Select: Exit For
        Next Cell

    'Takes the active column number and assigns it to the variable
        colNum = ActiveCell.Column

    'Finds a date match in that column
        For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(6, colNum), Cells(40, colNum))
        If Cell.Value = gsDate Then Cell.Select: Exit For
        Next Cell

'If the date is the same, it will overwrite the grade and status
        If ActiveCell.Value = gsDate Then

            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Moves One Cell Down

            ActiveCell.Value = gsGrade 'Prints the Grade from the GS

            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Moves One Cell Down

            ActiveCell.Value = gsStatus 'Prints the Status from the GS
```

Pick up my previous code where I match the event name on the INDEX page going across row 5.  Then, I assign the column number to the colNum variable.

Now, the new code: Since I grabbed the date from the Grade Sheet, I use the matched Event's column to search down to find the matching date.  If it finds a matching date, then it will overwrite the old with the new Grade and Status.  Otherwise, it will continue on with the code as previously written and find the first empty cell in the Event column and print the Date, Grade, and Status.

I hope this helps someone out there think through solving their problems, or at least gets you thinking towards a constructive solution...or you just learn something new, like I did!

I've gone from zero VBA knowledge to where I'm at now (still very much learning, but dangerous enough to impress the bosses) within a matter of just a couple weeks thanks to this website and everyone who contributed.  THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!